# content copy to another file using c

Tags: c

If I write

```
char ar[100];
strcpy(ar, "I am in child\n");
write(fd, ar, strlen(ar))
```

It will copy "I am in child" to file located in fd using open function.

But how to write

```
printf("you got %d points\n",dice);
```

to another file in C? `dice` is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`fprintf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fprintf).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int dice = 0;
    FILE* fp = fopen("your_file_name.txt", "w");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        perror("fopen");
        return 1;
    }
    fprintf(fp, "you got %d points\n", dice);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```